My python application doesn't want to cross-compile using Yocto
I'm currently trying to set up a Linux OS for one of our embedded projects, I've successfully cross-compiled many packages from pypi using the PiP2Bitbake package but when I tried to do it with a personal python script I couldn't achieve the same results, and I got the following errors : 
And here's the structure of my python script recipe
Notice that I've correctly mentionned the custom-layer I'm using in the bblayers.conf file, So my question would be: From where does this error come from and what should I do to correct it, thank you all in advance for your answers!
